# How do I include related model fields using Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Let's say that we have the following model:

```
class Classroom(models.Model):
    room_number = [...]

class Teacher(models.Model):
    name = [...]
    tenure = [...]
    classroom = models.ForeignKey(Classroom)
```

Let's say that instead of getting a result like this per the ManyRelatedPrimaryKeyField function:

```
{
    "room_number": "42", 
    "teachers": [
        27, 
        24, 
        7
    ]
},
```

have it return something that includes the full related model representation like:

```
{
    "room_number": "42", 
    "teachers": [
        {
           'id': 27,
           'name': 'John',
           'tenure': True
        }, 
        {
           'id': 24,
           'name': 'Sally',
           'tenure': False
        }, 
    ]
},
```

Is this possible? If so, how? And is this a bad idea?

Answer (score 294, accepted):

The simplest way is to use [the depth argument](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers#specifying-nested-serialization)

```
class ClassroomSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Classroom
        depth = 1
```

However, that will only include relationships for forward relationships, which in this case isn't quite what you need, since the teachers field is a reverse relationship.

If you've got more complex requirements (eg. include reverse relationships, nest some fields, but not others, or nest only a specific subset of fields) you can [nest serializers](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers#dealing-with-nested-objects), eg...

```
class TeacherSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Teacher
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'tenure')

class ClassroomSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    teachers = TeacherSerializer(source='teacher_set')

    class Meta:
        model = Classroom
```

Note that we use the source argument on the serializer field to specify the attribute to use as the source of the field.  We could drop the `source` argument by instead making sure the `teachers` attribute exists by using the [related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward) option on your `Teacher` model, ie. `classroom = models.ForeignKey(Classroom, related_name='teachers')`

One thing to keep in mind is that nested serializers do not currently support write operations.  For writable representations, you should use regular flat representations, such as pk or hyperlinking.

Comment: When I tried the first solution I didn't receive the Teachers, however I did receive instances of the parent of the Classroom (which this example does not show). In the second solution I received an error - "'Classroom' object has no attribute 'teachers'" . Am I missing something?

Comment: @Chaz Updated the answer to explain why `depth` wouldn't do what you need in this case, and to explain the exception you're seeing and how to deal with it.

Comment: @TomChristie Is it possible to allow for "added" fields, that is, added to the default set of fields? I'd like to show reverse relationships in my Model from other models.  I don't mind adding a field list of reverse relationships, but having to specify all of the normally default fields again seems rigid and fragile.

Comment: @WillBradley Nope. Let's continue the discussion on the ticket. https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/837

Comment: Does the `depth` thing work across many to many relationships?

Comment: I'm an idiot and was hitting the wrong server. It definitely works across many to many relationships.

Comment: Nesting serializers is awesome! I had to do this and was using DRF 3.1.0. I had to include `many=True` like so `...TeacherSerializer(source='teacher_set', many=True)`. Otherwise I was getting the following error: `The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the 'RelatedManager' instance.
Original exception text was: 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'type'.`

Comment: Hey @Tom Christie. I have kinda similar problem! But a bit different. I have two models, mealIngredient and Ingredient, mealIngredient has an fk to Ingredient, I want to be able to create a mealIngredient object by using id of the ingredient to be associated, but while retrieving a mealIngredient object via JSON I want to be able to see the complete ingredient object . Any idea how to go about it?

Comment: Hi @TomChristie, thanks for this answer. I'm struggling with this problem myself but one thing I don't understand is where the `_set` came from in `teachers = TeacherSerializer(source='teacher_set')`. I tried searching the DRF docs and came up with nothing. Any hints?

Comment: The reverse side of a ForeignKey will be named `..._set` by default. See the Django docs for more details: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager

Comment: What if I want depth on a specific field but not the other fields?

Comment: In that case include a nested serializer as an explicit field.

Comment: You will need `many=True` with `source='teacher_set' ` if it has more than one value else it will give null

Comment: Serializer also support write operations and there is a nice example in documents for writing nested serializers

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers

Comment: This solution will mean you can't create a classroom w/o including a teacher, what if i want to be able to create a class w/o including any teacher?

Answer (score 53):

Thank you @TomChristie!!!
You helped me a lot!
I would like to update that a little (because of a mistake I ran into)

```
class TeacherSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Teacher
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'tenure')

class ClassroomSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    teachers = TeacherSerializer(source='teacher_set', many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Classroom
        field = ("teachers",)
```

Comment: What do you do if you want to filter, teachers_set

Comment: You can add a `list_serializer_class` in `TeacherSerializer`, and add filtering logic by overriding the  `to_representation`  function of  the `list_serializer_class`.

Answer (score 8):

This can also be accomplished by using a pretty handy dandy django packaged called [drf-flex-fields](https://github.com/rsinger86/drf-flex-fields).  We use it and it's pretty awesome. You just install it `pip install drf-flex-fields`, pass it through your serializer, add `expandable_fields` and bingo (example below). It also allows you to specify deep nested relationships by using dot notation.

```
from rest_flex_fields import FlexFieldsModelSerializer

class ClassroomSerializer(FlexFieldsModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Model
        fields = ("teacher_set",)
        expandable_fields = {"teacher_set": (TeacherSerializer, {"source": "teacher_set"})}
```

Then you add `?expand=teacher_set` to your URL and it returns an expanded response.
Hope this helps someone, someday. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

## Thanks to @TomChristie and @Paolo

> I would just like to add a clarification, the below code works fine but the person has to remember to add the **related_name="teacher_set"** attribute to the Model Teacher. In this case here is the complete code :

### models.py

```py
class Classroom(models.Model):
    room_number = [...]

class Teacher(models.Model):
    name = [...]
    tenure = [...]
    classroom = models.ForeignKey(Classroom, related_name='teacher_set')
```

Note: *related_name='teacher_set'* to the *classroom* field.

### serializers.py

```sh
class TeacherSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Teacher
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'tenure')

class ClassroomSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    teachers = TeacherSerializer(source='teacher_set', many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Classroom
        field = ("teachers",)
```