# How to choose specific columns when using depth in serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model which consists of two `ForeignKeys`. I am only interested in parsing the content of the `ForeignKeys`, so i'm using the `depth` variable, which basically gives me all columns of the tables referenced with the FK. Is there a way to select which columns there should be included?

```
class SomeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyAwesomeModel
        fields = ('id', 'fk_one','fk_two')
        depth = 1
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using nested serializers. Documentation [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers.html#dealing-with-nested-objects).

Example:

```
class FKOneSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = FKOne
        fields = ('name', 'id')

class SomeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    fk_one = FKOneSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = MyAwesomeModel
        fields = ('id', 'fk_one','fk_two')
```

EDIT:

Similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573102/how-do-i-include-related-model-fields-using-django-rest-framework) by the creator of the Django Rest Framework. Also includes some related notes, including that nested serializers are read-only and that you may need to include a `source` argument on the serializer field.