# Doing related queries with python and django-rest-framework

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I'm starting with python and django-rest-framework.

The thing is that i have these 3 tables which i created thanks to Python Model.

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE "category" (
"id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
"name" varchar(50) NOT NULL
)
;
CREATE TABLE "branch" (
"id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
"name" varchar(200) NOT NULL,
"address" varchar(50) NOT NULL,
"area" varchar(50) NOT NULL,
"city" varchar(50) NOT NULL,
"state" varchar(50) NOT NULL,
"country" varchar(50) NOT NULL,
"latitude" double precision NOT NULL,
"longitude" double precision NOT NULL,
"ip_controller" varchar(15) NOT NULL
)
;
CREATE TABLE "category_xx_branch" (
"id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
"branch_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "branch" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
"category_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "category" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
"last_ticket_issued" varchar(50) NOT NULL,
"last_ticket_called" varchar(50) NOT NULL,
"estimated_waiting_time" integer NOT NULL
)
;
```

Now with rest i need to give a json response like these..

```
{"branch":"branchdata",
 "categoryData":["categoryData", "last_ticket_issued", "last_ticket_called", "estimated_waiting_time"]}
```

What i have in my python model is:

```
class Category (models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Meta:
    db_table = 'category'

class Branch (models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
area = models.CharField(max_length=50)
city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
state = models.CharField(max_length=50)
country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
latitude = models.FloatField()
longitude = models.FloatField()
ip_controller = models.CharField(max_length=15)
categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, through='CategoryPerBranch')

class Meta():
    db_table = 'branch'

class CategoryPerBranch (models.Model):
branch = models.ForeignKey(Branch, related_name='branch')
category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='category')
last_ticket_issued = models.CharField(max_length=50)
last_ticket_called = models.CharField(max_length=50)
estimated_waiting_time = models.IntegerField()
class Meta:
    db_table = 'category_xx_branch'
```

How i can work this out so i can have the json response as i want ?

With these setup i have this json response

> {
>           "id": 1, 
>           "name": "Sucursal 1", 
>           "address": "Av. Siempre Viva 123", 
>           "area": "Santiago", 
>           "city": "Santiago", 
>           "state": "Santiago", 
>           "country": "Chile", 
>           "latitude": -33.399902, 
>           "longitude": -70.553126, 
>           "ip_controller": "192.168.0.210", 
>           "categories": [
>               {
>                   "id": 3, 
>                   "name": "Otro"
>               }, 
>               {
>                   "id": 2, 
>                   "name": "Empresa"
>               }, 
>               {
>                   "id": 1, 
>                   "name": "Persona"
>               }
>           ]
>       }

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I include related model fields using Django Rest Framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573102/how-do-i-include-related-model-fields-using-django-rest-framework)

Comment: I don't know if this is a duplicate.. because i want to achieve this through the model