# Using nested serializer as related field in Django Rest Framework

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework

I have two simple serializers:

```
class ZoneSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Zone
        fields = ('id', 'name')

class CitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    zone = ZoneSerializer(source='zone')

    class Meta:
        model = City
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'zone')
```

So client-side receives JSON objects like:

```
{
    "id": 11, 
    "name": "City1", 
    "zone": {
        "id": 2, 
        "name": "Zone 2"
    }
}
```

Now, when I receive JSON from client-side as...

```
{
    "name": "NewCity",
    "zone": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Zone 2"
    }
}
```

... and want to POST (create) it as a new "city", I want my ModelSerializer to know that "zone" in JSON is a foreign key to Zone model, and it shouldn't be inserted to db as a new "zone".

Is there a way to achieve that? Or must I use `RelatedField` instead, although I want to pass and receive full detailed zone rather than just primary keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14581826/2789332) by the author of django-rest-framework, the answer is no, it is not possible ("nested serializers do not currently support write operations") as of January 2013.