# Django get all, with related models

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

**Problem:**

I'm using Django Rest Framework and i want to fetch all models with the relationships included, like this:

```
TestModel.objects.all()
```

My model looks like this:

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
   related_model = models.ForeignKey(TestRelation)
```

Problem is, i only get the Primary Keys for `related_model` but i need the whole `related_model`!

I'm using the ListCreateAPIView, with the above queryset (`TestModel.objects.all()`) and the most basic form of the ModelSerializer.

I tried the `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` but i get the same result..

Thanks!

Comment: Found my answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573102/how-do-i-include-related-model-fields-using-django-rest-framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create serializer for your related model:

```
class TestRelationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        meta = TestRelation
```

and use is as field in `TestModelSerializer`:

```
class TestModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    related_model = TestRelationSerializer()
```

You can also do it other way around, by using `TestModelSerializer` as field in `TestRelationSerializer` with many set to true:

```
class TestRelationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    testmodel_set = TestModelSerializer(many=True)
```

just remember, you can't do both at once due to infinite recursion it makes.