# Customized and nested response from django rest framework

Tags: python, django, rest

I have these models the for django and django-rest framework.

```
class ProductType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    type = models.ForeignKey(ProductType)

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Attribute(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    type = models.ForeignKey(ProductType)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
```

Model objects are saved like

Product Type

```
[{"id" : 1, "name": "Type A"}, 
 {"id" : 2, "name": "Type B"}]
```

Platform

```
[{"id" : 1, "name": "Product A", "type": 1}, 
 {"id" : 2, "name": "Product B", "type": 2}]
```

Category

```
[{"id" : 1, "name": "Category A"}, 
 {"id" : 2, "name": "Category B"},
 {"id" : 3, "name": "Category C"}]
```

Attribute

```
[{"id" : 1, "name": "Attribute A", "category":1, "type": 1}, 
 {"id" : 2, "name": "Attribute B", "category":1, "type": 2}, 
 {"id" : 3, "name": "Attribute C", "category":1, "type": 1}, 
 {"id" : 4, "name": "Attribute D", "category":1, "type": 1}, 
 {"id" : 5, "name": "Attribute E", "category":2, "type": 1}, 
 {"id" : 6, "name": "Attribute F", "category":2, "type": 1}, 
 {"id" : 7, "name": "Attribute G", "category":2, "type": 2}, 
 {"id" : 8, "name": "Attribute H", "category":3, "type": 2}, 
 {"id" : 9, "name": "Attribute I", "category":3, "type": 2}]
```

and I want to get a Product object with PK=1 as described below

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Product A",
    "type": 1,
    "categories": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Category A",
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Attribute A"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Attribute C"
                },
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "name": "Attribute D"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Category B",
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "id": 5,
                    "name": "Attribute E"
                },
                {
                    "id": 6,
                    "name": "Attribute F"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Currently, I am querying each of the models, then reorganize results in the client as I desire.

However, I would like to do the same tasks in the server side to make the client code simple.

**Notice, Platform and Category are not directly related.**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I include related model fields using Django Rest Framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573102/how-do-i-include-related-model-fields-using-django-rest-framework)

Comment: @Ivan I've already tried the depth option and nested serializer, but they didn't work because two models are not directly related in my case. I think I have to create JSON response manually and I want to know what the best way is.