# Django Rest framework, how to include '__all__' fields and a related field in ModelSerializer ?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have two models, one with M2M relation and a related name. I want to include **all** fields in the serializer and the related field.

models.py:

```
class Pizza(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    toppings = models.ManyToManyField(Topping, null=True, blank=True, related_name='pizzas')

class Topping(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

serializer.py:

```
class ToppingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Topping
        fields = '__all__'
```

This works but it doesn't include the related field.

```
 fields = ['name', 'price', 'pizzas']
```

This works exactly as I want, but what happens when Toppings model has a lot of fields. I want to do something like :

```
fields = ['__all__', 'pizzas']
```

This syntax results in an error saying:

> Field name `__all__` is not valid for model

Is there a way to achieve the wanted behavior? Or the fields must be typed manually when using a related name ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573102/how-do-i-include-related-model-fields-using-django-rest-framework - The answer cannot get any better - it if from the author himself.

Comment: @karthikr This doesn't really explain how to do what I want. It just explains how to nest M2M. I don't want to do that. I want to include related fields and the __all__ tag in the serializer 'fields'

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I just checked the source code of Django Rest Framework.
The behaviour you want seems not to be supported in the Framework.

The `fields` option must be a list, a tuple or the text `__all__`.

Here is a snippet of the relevant source code:

```
    ALL_FIELDS = '__all__'
    if fields and fields != ALL_FIELDS and not isinstance(fields, (list, tuple)):
        raise TypeError(
            'The `fields` option must be a list or tuple or "__all__". '
            'Got %s.' % type(fields).__name__
        )
```

You cannot add '**all**' additionally to the tuple or list with fields...

Comment: man, this is such a basic feature, every time I look into django it looks like everything is broken or set on stone, no way to make smart factories or anything, just write a ton of useless code for any simple thing you want to do.
thanks for the answer

Answer (score 73):

Like @DanEEStart said, DjangoRestFramework don't have a simple way to extend the '**all**' value for fields, because the `get_field_names` methods seems to be designed [to work that way](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L1019).

But fortunately you can override this method to allow a simple way to include all fields and relations without enumerate a tons of fields.

I override this method like this:

```
class ToppingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Topping
        fields = '__all__'
        extra_fields = ['pizzas']

    def get_field_names(self, declared_fields, info):
        expanded_fields = super(ToppingSerializer, self).get_field_names(declared_fields, info)

        if getattr(self.Meta, 'extra_fields', None):
            return expanded_fields + self.Meta.extra_fields
        else:
            return expanded_fields
```

Note that this method only change the behaviour of this serializer, and the `extra_fields` attribute only works on this serializer class.

If you have a tons of serializer like this, you can create a intermediate class to include this `get_fields_names` method in one place and reuse'em many times. Some like this:

```
class CustomSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    def get_field_names(self, declared_fields, info):
        expanded_fields = super(CustomSerializer, self).get_field_names(declared_fields, info)

        if getattr(self.Meta, 'extra_fields', None):
            return expanded_fields + self.Meta.extra_fields
        else:
            return expanded_fields


class ToppingSerializer(CustomSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Topping
        fields = '__all__'
        extra_fields = ['pizzas']

class AnotherSerializer(CustomSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'
        extra_fields = ['comments']
```

Comment: I just want to let you know that you are a lifesaver and thank you so much for this snippet.

Comment: Why on earth isn't this built-in. Or why aren't reverse relationships included in '__all__'

Comment: I'm sitting here in 2024 and this solution still works for Django 4.2 and DRF 3.14.0. Thanks, @hugoruscitti!

Answer (score 33):

The `fields="__all__"` option can work by specifying an additional field manually as per the following examples. This is by far the cleanest solution around for this issue.

**Nested Relationships**

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships

```
class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = '__all__'

class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks = TrackSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = '__all__'
```

I would assume this would work for any of the other related field options listed on the same page: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#serializer-relations

**Reverse relation example**

```
class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    album = AlbumSerializer(source='album_id')

    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = '__all__'
```

**Note:** *Created using Django Rest Framework version 3.6.2, subject to change. Please add a comment if any future changes break any examples posted above.*

Comment: this would not work in case of reverse relations -> http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#reverse-relations

Comment: @IshanKhare Updated to show that this can also work with reverse relationships.

Comment: This should really be accepted as the correct answer, as it solves the problem within the provided functionality of the framework without additional hacking.

Answer (score 29):

Hi I could achieve the expected result by using [Django's _meta API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/meta/) , which seems to be available since Django 1.11. So in my serializer I did:

```
model = MyModel
fields = [field.name for field in model._meta.fields]
fields.append('any_other_field')
```

In programming there's always many ways to achieve the same result, but this one above, has really worked for me.

Cheers!

Comment: this one is so clean!

Comment: This won't work if you declare extra fields in your serializer, that are not in the model. E.g. if you need to send extra data at the point of serialization. Therefore, it shouldn't be accepted as a generally working solution.

Answer (score 10):

If you are trying to basically just add extra piece of information into the serialized object, you don't need to change the fields part at all. To add a field you do:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   ...
   new_field = serializers.SerializerMethodField('new_field_method')

   def new_field_method(self, modelPointer_):
      return "MY VALUE"
```

Then you can still use

```
class Meta:
   fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. thanks !

Comment: This is a read-only field!

Answer (score 3):

to include all the fields and the other fields defined in your serializer you can just say `exclude = ()`

```
class ToppingSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
   pizzas = '<>' #the extra attribute value
    class Meta:
        model = Topping
        exclude = ()
```

This will list all the field values with the extra argument pizzas

Answer (score 0):

This is how i did it, much more easier

```py
class OperativeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Operative
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ('name','objective',)
        widgets = {'__all__':'required'}
```

Comment: Getting this error : `Cannot set both 'fields' and 'exclude' options on serializer`

Comment: error in setting both fields and exclude options. but thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

Building on top of @Wand's wonderful answer:

```
def build_fields(mdl,extra=[],exclude=[]):
    fields = [field.name for field in mdl._meta.fields if field.name not in exclude]
    fields += extra
    return fields
```

Usage:

```
model = User
fields = build_fields(model, ['snippets'], ['password'])
```

Will return all fields from the User model, with the related field snippets, without the password field.