# Django Rest Framework ModelSerializer all fields not working properly

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, serialization

I'm trying to get all the fields and functions from my model.
It works well with the fields but it doesn't get the functions.

models.py snippet:

```
email = models.EmailField(_('Email'), null=True, blank=True)



@property
def function_name(self):
    return ...
```

serializers.py snippet:

```
class ModelNameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = ModelName
    fields = '__all__'
```

If i call `serializers.data` from views.py, i get the field email but not the return value of the function.

If i do `fields = ('function_name',)`, then i get the return value of the function but not anymore all the other fields.

How can i get all fields and functions from my model?

I hope that i could explain my problem.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38245414/django-rest-framework-how-to-include-all-fields-and-a-related-field-in-mo)

Comment: @ABDULNIYASPM Thank you, the second answer worked well.