# How can i add @property field to django rest serializer with '__all__'

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have model

```
class A(models.Model):
    is_enable = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    updated_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    show_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    answers_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    audience = JSONField()
    events = JSONField()
    rules = JSONField()
    message = models.TextField(blank=True)

    @property
    def conversion(self):
        if self.show_count == 0:
            return 0.0
        return (self.answers_count / self.show_count) * 100
```

And i have serializer

```
class ASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    audience = serializers.JSONField()
    events = serializers.JSONField()
    rules = serializers.JSONField()

    class Meta:
        model = Trigger
        fields = '__all__'
```

I want to add to response @property conversion` field
and I want to do something like this in serializer

```
class Meta:
            model = Trigger
            fields = '__all__' + conversion
```

I know that i can make something like this

```
class Meta:
                model = Trigger
                fields = ('is_enable', 'title' ... 'conversion')
```

But i want add all fields and conversion field and do this more beautiful

Answer (score 0):

you can use somethig like this:

```
class ModelMixin:
    @classmethod
    def _get_model_fields(cls):
        all_fields = cls._meta.get_fields()
        fields = [i.name for i in all_fields if i.__class__.__name__ not in ['ManyToManyRel', 'GenericRelation', 'ManyToOneRel']]
        return fields
    @classmethod
    def get_serializer_fields(cls):
        fields = cls._get_model_fields()
        return fields

class A(ModelMixin, models.Model):
    ...

class ASerializer(ModelSerializer):
    custom_field = serializers.JSONField()
    class Meta:
        model = A
        fields = A.get_serializer_fields()
        fields.append('cusom_field')
```

Comment: I want more simple and beautiful but this looks more harder than the option when I will list all the fields `fields = ('is_enable', 'title' ... 'conversion')` So waiting another way.

Answer (score 0):

Might still not be as clean as you want it to be, but using `<model>._meta.fields` you can get all fields of that model, and using the `name` property of each field you can retrieve the names that refer to them.
As the serializers file is interpreted as python, it supports code execution, meaning you can use all python functionalities when setting properties, including a for loop, which gives us the ability to do this:

```
fields = (tuple((f.name for f in A._meta.fields)) + ('conversion',))
```

Needed this for my own model as well and there it seemed to work, so hopefully so does it for you.

Comment: Very interesting way of achieving it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a SerializerMethodField in your serializer and later define a method in serializer itself that can call your functions you defined in models using @property

```
class ASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    audience = serializers.JSONField()
    events = serializers.JSONField()
    rules = serializers.JSONField()
    conversion = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Trigger
        fields = '__all__'
    
    def get_conversion(self,obj):
        return obj.conversion
```

This should allow you to keep your code *beautiful* without modifying much of your code.

Comment: Yes, it possible but I try to find some easy way for it, without ton of extra code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late in this thread but the cleanest solution (to me) I found is the one given by `hugoruscitti` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41063577/12085129) (all credits to him).

It consists in creating an intermediary Serializer class that you'll be able to use everywhere.

Something like this :

```py
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer


class CustomSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    def get_field_names(self, declared_fields, info):
        expanded_fields = super().get_field_names(declared_fields, info)
        if hasattr(self.Meta, "extra_fields"):
            return expanded_fields + self.Meta.extra_fields
        else:
            return expanded_fields

# Then you can reuse it like so:

class MyFirstSerializer(CustomSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = MyFirstModel
        fields = "__all__"
        extra_fields = ["other_field_1", "other_field_2"]

# or :

class MySecondSerializer(CustomSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = MySecondModel
        fields = "__all__"
```

This should solve your issue in a clean way.

Comment: Yes, it looks interesting to extend base with additional logic, thank you.