# ModelSerializer: include all fields and all properties of a model

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Using the following model that defines a property:

```
class Invitation(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField()
    to_email = models.EmailField()
    message = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

    @property
    def expiry_date(self):
        return self.created + datetime.timedelta(days=30)
```

How I can specify in the model serializer that I want to include **all** fields and **all** properties? Do they have to all be listed in the `fields` option one by one or is there some magic way of combining `'__all__'` and `expiry_date`?

Comment: I'm not sure there is a way to combine them, although you may be able to do similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41063577/2091925

Comment: @WillKeeling Thanks, that does answer my question! I'll mark this as a dupe of the other one since it offers a good enough solution.