# Django DRF nested serializers are not linked

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to build an API for a picture gallery using Django and Django Rest Framework for the API.

I have set up the following two models:

```py
class Album(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    parent_album = models.ForeignKey('self',
                                     null=True,
                                     blank=True,
                                     on_delete=models.CASCADE
                                    )

class Picture(models.Model):
    path = models.ImageField()
    album = models.ForeignKey('Album', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

For the serializers, I have defined the following, using the official [Django DRF doc](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships):

```py
class PictureSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Picture
        fields = '__all__'


class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    pictures = PictureSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = '__all__'
```

Now, I have some objects already defined, so I wanted to try in a shell:

```py
>>> album = Album.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> len(Picture.objects.filter(album__exact=Album.objects.get(pk=1)))
3
>>> AlbumSerializer(instance=album).data
{'id': 1, 'name': 'First album', 'description': '', 'start_date': '2019-08-15', 'end_date': None, 'parent_album': None}
>>> AlbumSerializer()
AlbumSerializer():
    id = IntegerField(label='ID', read_only=True)
    pictures = PictureSerializer(many=True, read_only=True):
        id = IntegerField(label='ID', read_only=True)
        path = ImageField(max_length=100)
        album = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Album.objects.all())
    name = CharField(max_length=100)
    description = CharField(allow_blank=True, allow_null=True, required=False, style={'base_template': 'textarea.html'})
    start_date = DateField()
    end_date = DateField(allow_null=True, required=False)
    parent_album = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(allow_null=True, queryset=Album.objects.all(), required=False)
```

You will notice that there are no `pictures` in the serialized data, but the field is there when I print the serializer, and that's my problem... Have I missed something somewhere?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You want the serialized data to have a `pictures` atribute with an empty array or null value?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django Rest framework, how to include '\_\_all\_\_' fields and a related field in ModelSerializer ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38245414/django-rest-framework-how-to-include-all-fields-and-a-related-field-in-mo)

Comment: @iklinac That's not the case, wrong dupe, see my answer

Comment: I've posted an answer, did it helped? Did I miss something? Please let me know ;D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is due to the [related name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) given to ForeignKeys.

Right now with the code you provided the name backwards relation name should be `picture_set`. So for the serializer to work you should change it do the following:

```
class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    picture_set = PictureSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = '__all__'
```

But, if you want to display as `pictures` you can also do the following:

```
class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    pictures = PictureSerializer(many=True, read_only=True, source='picture_set')

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = '__all__'
```

Finally, if you want to get rid of the `picture_set` you should change your code to the following:

**models.py**

```
class Picture(models.Model):
    path = models.ImageField()
    album = models.ForeignKey('Album', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='pictures')
```

**serializers.py**

```
class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    pictures = PictureSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Note that reverse relationships are not automatically included by the ModelSerializer and HyperlinkedModelSerializer classes. To include a reverse relationship, you must explicitly add it to the fields list -> https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#reverse-relations

Comment: @iklinac That's why he manually added the field to the serializer with `pictures = PictureSerializer(..)`

Comment: I added `related_name='pictures'` in the `Picture` model, and that worked fine with `fields = '__all__'`, thanks a lot!