# Serialize ID and URL at the same time Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm starting with **DRF** and i would like to serialize both `ID` and `Hyperlinked URL` at the same time.

Let me define a simple example model:

```py
class Account(model.Models):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    active = models.BooleanField()
```

---

I know that there is a `ModelSerializer` which represents the object as follows:

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "name": "library",
   "active": true
}
```

And there is as well an `HyperlinkedModelSerializer` which represents the object as follows:

```
{
   "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/core/accounts/1/",
   "name": "library",
   "active": true
}
```

Intrinsically in the `HyperlinkedModelSerializer` we can retrieve the row's ID, but **what I'm looking for** is to get something like this:

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/core/accounts/1/",
   "name": "library",
   "active": true
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50880256/7207673) it works well for me.

Doing this you can avoid to define model's fields and after that define them again in the serializer with the `id` and `url` fields like `['url', 'id', 'name', 'active']`

With the example it seems dummy but this can save you a lot of time when you deal with models which have much more fields ...

```py
class AccountSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = [field.name for field in model._meta.fields]
        fields.extend(['id', 'url'])
```

Answer (score 2):

I checked the [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#hyperlinkedmodelserializer), you can explicitly add the field 'id' by including it in `fields`.

```
class AccountSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ['url', 'id', 'name', 'active']
```

Comment: Excellent !   It means that `fields = '__all__'` doesn't serialize all related fields? I'm saying this because i wouldn't like to repeat myself and keep it simple, i mean ... what i'm avoiding is to define my model fields and after that define them again in the serializer.

Comment: Can i do something like prepending the id like `fields = ['id'] + ['__all__']` ?

Comment: Normally id would be automatically included in `__all__`, but HyperLinkedModelSerializer replaces 'id' with 'url'.

Comment: Sadly, [DRF serializers don't support `__all__` and additional fields.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38245414/django-rest-framework-how-to-include-all-fields-and-a-related-field-in-mo/40363515)

It's either a list, tuple, or the string '__all__', but not a combination. So the best option here is to specify your fields manually. (Or use a cusomt extende HyperLinkedModelSerializer subclass)

Answer (score 0):

You should add this to the Nginx config file:

```
location /api/ {
        .
        .
        .
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        .
        .
        .
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).