# How do i access another column from related table other than the foreign key, when creating an API view

Tags: reactjs, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

Im using django for a web app and i am creating REST API views. Is there a way i can access two tables in one view? If not, how can can i retrieve a non-foreign key column from a related record. The below code is retrieving a vase record based on a URL parameter. I want to access the artistName which is stored in artist table (a one-to-many with Vase table), not artist_id which is stored in Vase

```
class FilterVases(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = VaseSerializer 
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Vase.objects.all()
        artist_id = self.request.query_params.get('artist_id')
        if artist_id is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(artist_id=artist_id)
        vaseID = self.request.query_params.get('vaseID')
        if vaseID is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(vaseID=vaseID)
        return queryset
```

**edited to add**
This is models for Artist and Vase:

```
class Artist(models.Model) :
        artistID = models.CharField(max_length=10)
        artistName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    
class Vase(models.Model):
        vaseID = models.CharField(max_length=10) 
        vaseRef = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
        inscription = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
        fabric = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True,null=True)
        subject = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
        technique = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True)
        height = models.FloatField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True)
        diameter = models.FloatField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True) 
        shape = models.ForeignKey(Shape, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        provenance = models.ForeignKey(Provenance, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Please share the models of both vase and artist

Comment: You can do it with extend VaseSerializer. If you add artist field as nested serializer to VaseSerializer, you can serve vases with their artists. If you do that, use select_related('artis') in your query, It will prevent too many queries.

Comment: @abdullah edited and added the models above, thank you

Comment: @kamilyrb would i do that in VaseSerializer in serializer.py?

Comment: @EmilyCat111 check my below answer. I have implemented the same for an app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Vase model add this:

```
def artist_name(self):
        return self.artist.artistName
```

Hence, it will look like:

```
class Vase(models.Model):
        vaseID = models.CharField(max_length=10) 
        vaseRef = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
        inscription = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
        fabric = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True,null=True)
        subject = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
        technique = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True)
        height = models.FloatField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True)
        diameter = models.FloatField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True) 
        shape = models.ForeignKey(Shape, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        provenance = models.ForeignKey(Provenance, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

        def artist_name(self):
            return self.artist.artistName
```

In the VaseSerializer add the 'artist_name' to the fields Meta.

If you want to add this custom fields to all Vase Model fields, refer to this topic [Django Rest framework, how to include '__all__' fields and a related field in ModelSerializer ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38245414/django-rest-framework-how-to-include-all-fields-and-a-related-field-in-mo)

```
class VaseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Vase
        fields = '__all__'
        extra_fields = ['artist_name']

    def get_field_names(self, declared_fields, info):
        expanded_fields = super(VaseSerializer, self).get_field_names(
            declared_fields, info)

        if getattr(self.Meta, 'extra_fields', None):
            return expanded_fields + self.Meta.extra_fields
        else:
            return expanded_fields
```

Below should your view:

```
class FilterVases(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = VaseSerializer 
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Vase.objects.all()
        query_artist = self.request.query_params.get('artist_name')
        if query_artist is not None:
            try:
                artist = Artist.objects.get(artistName=query_artist)
                queryset = queryset.filter(artist=artist)
            except:
                pass
        vaseID = self.request.query_params.get('vaseID')
        if vaseID is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(vaseID=vaseID)
        return queryset
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I got tried your code (but updated the extra_fields to artistName, and updated the view to artistName instead of artist_id) and i got the following error:

django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'artistName' into field. Choices are: artist, artist_id, collection, collection_id, diameter, fabric, height, id, inscription, pastcollection, plate, provenance, provenance_id, pubschovase, shape, shape_id, subject, technique, vaseID, vaseRef

Comment: To clarify, the error i've received was when i tried to pass through an artistName as a URL parameter

Comment: Another update (sorry!), i realised when i pass the artist_id through as a URL parameter i get the artist name data perfectly fine, so thank you for your help with this. So i just need to update my API view to be able to accept a URL parameter of artist name instead on artist id, as generally people wont be searching with the artist id they will be searching by their name. Any ideas?

Comment: Check the above answer, I have added amended the FilterVases class.

Comment: queryset = queryset.filter(artist.artistName=artist_name)
                               ^
SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?

i got this syntax error. Then I tried with == and i got this error :        NameError: name 'artist' is not defined

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Try the updated FilterVases.

Comment: You’re welcome! You may need to mark the answer as correct :).