# How to get data related to a foreign key in django rest framework?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have to create an appointment for an event, my model is as follows -

event/models.py

```
class Event(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    event_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    event_location = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
```

appointment/models.py

```
class Appointment(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    appointment_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
```

And appointment serializer is -

appointment/serializers.py

```
class AppointmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Appointment
        fields = ('id', 'event', 'appointment_date')
```

I am able to create appointment as follows -

```
POST appointment

request params -
    event:6625dc74-dc36-4a22-9fac-c63e96fe6049
    appointment_date:2017-06-26 18:30:00


response
    {
      "id": "08c975bc-c4d8-4e90-a4b2-bdb2cd69e9e8",
      "event": "6625dc74-dc36-4a22-9fac-c63e96fe6049",
      "appointment_date": "2017-06-26 18:30:00"
    }
```

But I need event as event object, rather than event id string, like -

```
[
  "id": "08c975bc-c4d8-4e90-a4b2-bdb2cd69e9e8",
  "event": {
        "id": "6625dc74-dc36-4a22-9fac-c63e96fe6049",
        "event_name": "Test Event",
        "event_location": "TVM, IND"
  },
  "appointment_date": "2017-06-26 18:30:00"
]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I include related model fields using Django Rest Framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573102/how-do-i-include-related-model-fields-using-django-rest-framework)

Comment: This has been documented in [DRF docs - Serializer relations](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your serializer class define `depth=1`

So your serializer will be:

```
class AppointmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Appointment
    fields = ('id', 'event', 'appointment_date')
    depth = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
While adding depth = 1, event is missing in POSTed data. Please note that, I am passing event id as POST parameter. 

ie, event:6625dc74-dc36-4a22-9fac-c63e96fe6049