# Django follow primary key JSON

Tags: python, json, django

I relatively new to Django, but im trying to return the complete JSON document for the following data model.

```
class Wheels(models.Model):
   w_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   w_weight = models.IntegerField(default=200)
   w_size = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   w_durability = models.IntegerField(default=45)

   def __str__(self):
    return self.w_name

class Chassis(models.Model):
    c_owner = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    c_year = models.IntegerField(default=1900)
    c_model = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    c_wheels = models.ForeignKey(Wheels)
    c_weight = models.IntegerField(default=20)

    def __str__(self):
      return self.c_model`
```

Right now the code returns just:

```
{
"id": 1,
"c_owner": "Mike",
"c_year": 1969,
"c_model": "Chevy",
"c_weight": 3500,
"c_wheels": 1
}
```

But instead of the 1 for wheels i would like it to follow the wheels table

Views:

```
class ChassisList(ModelViewSet):
   queryset = Chassis.objects.all()
   serializer_class = ChassisSerializer


class WheelsList(ModelViewSet):
   queryset = Wheels.objects.all()
   serializer_class = WheelSerializer
```

Serializers:

```
class WheelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
    model = Wheels
    fields = ('__all__')

class ChassisSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
    model = Chassis
    fields = ('__all__')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I include related model fields using Django Rest Framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573102/how-do-i-include-related-model-fields-using-django-rest-framework)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution:

```
class ChassisSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
    model = Chassis
    fields = ('__all__')
    depth = 1
```

Comment: Thanks Serg!  I like those kind of solutions :)