# How do I get the whole JSON object in Django using DRF3?

Tags: python, json, django

When I make a call to my API (curl), I get the following:

```
{"id": 1, "name": "Sword", "persona": [1]}
```

I'm getting the 'id' of the persona, but not the properties within. How do I do this?

Models.py:

```
class Persona(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    icon = models.CharField(max_length=255,default='1')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Equipment(models.Model):
    personas = models.ManyToManyField(Persona)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Serializers.py:

```
class EquipmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    personas = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Persona.objects.all(), many=True)
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        model = Equipment
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'persona')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two steps:

1. Create a `Persona serializer class`:

   ```
   class PersonaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
       class Meta:
           model = Persona
   ```
2. Then you can "chain" this serializer to the `Equipement` one:

   ```
   class EquipmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
       personas = PersonaSerializer(source='personas', many=True)
       name = serializers.CharField(max_length=255)

       class Meta:
           model = Equipment
           fields = ('id', 'name', 'personas')
   ```

For a deeper understanding of the above, have a look at this exemplary answer:

[How do I include related model fields using Django Rest Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573102/how-do-i-include-related-model-fields-using-django-rest-framework?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Good luck :)