# How to return data from two different tables in django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have two models in my models.py. I need to return a json response which includes data from two tables.
How should my view and serializer look like?

```
class Device(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    device_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.device_name)

class StatusActivity(models.Model):
    OFFLINE = 1
    ONLINE = 2
    STATUS = (
        (OFFLINE, ('Offline')),
        (ONLINE, ('Online')),
    )
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    device_id = models.ForeignKey(Device, related_name='StatusActivity', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    changed_to = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=STATUS)
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.device_id)
```

Expected Response:

```
 {
    "device_id":"",
    "device_name":"",
    "changed_to":"",
    "modified_at":"",
  }
```

UPDATE:
I set my views.py and serializer.py as below. I am checking

**Serializer.py**

```
class DeviceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Device
        fields = '__all__'

class StatusActivitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = StatusActivity
        fields = '__all__'

class ListSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    # devices = DeviceSerializer(many=True)
    # activities = StatusActivitySerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = [Device, StatusActivity]
        fields = ['device_id', 'device_name', 'changed_to', 'modified_at']
```

**Views.py**

```
class DeviceListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Device.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ListSerializer

class StatusActivityListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = StatusActivity.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StatusActivitySerializer
```

Comment: What you have tried? Show some effort

Comment: Why do you have 2 views? If you want one response, you should have only one view.

Comment: Okey, and how it should look like? I still can not retrieve a data like a describe in my question above. Can you point how can i do that? @dirkgroten

Comment: First, are you fetching a `Device` or a `StatusActivity` (i.e. which pk/id is passed in your url)? Create the serializer for that model, then add the fields from the other model manually by specifying the [`source`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you don't need to have two separated views for this, because you can easily serialize relations from one serializer class. 
Take a look at this useful answer: [How do I include related model fields using Django Rest Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573102/how-do-i-include-related-model-fields-using-django-rest-framework)

For your case you can write something like this:

```
class StatusActivitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    device_name = serializers.CharField(source='device_id.device_name')

    class Meta:
        model = StatusActivity
        fields = ('changed_to', 'modified_at', 'device_id', 'device_name')
```

Something that worth to note:

1. it's a good idea for ForeignKey field use `device` name instead of
   `device_id`;
2. related_name arg should have a name for reverse access. Keep it
   meaningful, e.g. `status_activities` is a good choice.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It gives me what I need. But I didn't understand your first point. Why should I use device_name instead of device_id?
@funnydman

Comment: @erondem Ah, actually there is misunderstanding I'm specially highting `device` and `device_id` to make the difference. You should use `device` instead of `device_id` because Django automatically appends  `_id` postfix, so in your case you'll have `device_id_id` field and more likely that is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

filter the status activity. you can refer the foreignkey.
 eg:

```
items = []
for statusact in StatusActivity.objects.all():
    items.append({
        "device_id":statusact.device_id.id,
        "device_name":statusact.device_id.device_name,
        "changed_to":statusact.changed_to,
        "modified_at":statusact.modified_at,
    })
```

Comment: I have 3 entry in db but it respond me this [
  {},
  {},
  {}
]