# How can I get the count of nested model relationship?

Tags: django

Here are my model relationships:

```
|---Retailer
    |---Product
        |---Coupon
```

Now I have a view that returns me each retailer with its products:

```
class ProductList(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        retailer = Retailer.objects.all()
        serializer = RetailerSerializer(retailer, many=True)
        data = serializer.data
        return JsonResponse({'data': data}, safe=False)
```

And here's RetailerSerializer:

```
class RetailerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    products = ProductSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Retailer
        fields = ['name', 'website','description', 'products']
        depth = 1
```

Now I want to get count coupons in each product. What should i do?

Comment: add your relevant portions of model class

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14581826/10349590

Answer (score 1):

Add following line into your `ProductSerializer`

```
def to_representation(self, instance):
    reps = super().to_representation(instance)
    reps['coupons_count'] = instance.coupon_set.all().count()
    return reps
```

Rename `coupon_set` in `instance.coupon_set.all().count()` with your backward relation name. The default name is `coupon_set` but you can change it by specify `related_name` in `Coupon` model that related into `Product` model

Comment: Thank a lot. it worked but I think I should edit my question title can you help me with that?